# Column chart from pivoted table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I need some help with the next problem, I'm new at Power BI btw. I have next data structure:

[image: data_table]

So, I need to get a visualization per year and separated by [app,repp], something like this:

[image: Example]

But, in the same visual I need to get separated by years, I mean 2020[app, repp], 2021[app, repp] and 2022[app, repp]. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Your question probably got downvoted because you provided the sample data as jpeg and not as a copyable markdown table. This is a no-go on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your Excel pivot table, which is intuitive to read, but bad for visualizations. You'll have to unpivot it first using PowerQuery:

[image]

With

```
Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Student"}, "Year", "Status")
```

you'll get

[image]

From here it's straight forward to build a clustered column chart with

- X-axis: Year
- Y-axis: Count of Student
- Lengend: Status

[image]

You could also swap X-axis amd Legend to get something like this:

[image]